# dataframe append not visible out of function scope

Tags: python, pandas, pass-by-reference

According to my understanding of python, mutable references to data can be modified within a function scope and reflect the change outside. However the behavior below confuses me:

1) Consider a list:

```
my_list = []
def checklistappend( list ):
    list.append( 1 )
checklistappend( my_list )
print ( my_list )
```

As expected the variable  my_list = [1]

2) However consider the following scenario with a dataframe:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])
def checkdfappend ( df ):
    df.append( [1] )
checkdfappend( my_df )
print( my_df )
```

In this case the result of my_df is still an empty data frame with columns 'A' which is non-intuitive and the only explaination I can come up with is that the dataframe append method internally assigns to a new variable which is the behavior I would not expect.

I am using python 2.7.2 with pandas 0.13.1 , changing either of which is not in my control.

Is there another way to achieve the same objective without making so many copies ?

Comment: Maybe stupid question but have you tried without the function? I mean apply to my_df direclty

Comment: [append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is not an inplace operation. It returns a new dataframe. So you are not actually modifying the object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the output back to `df`.

```
df = df.append([1])
```